# How do get a high-resolution UML Class Diagram from IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml, jetbrains-ide

For a project, I wanted to auto-generate UML class diagrams from a Java package, for which IntelliJ provides a feature. However, this generates low-resolution images in `.png` format when saving and attempting to print and save as PDF generates strange text artefacts. How do I get a high-res UML class diagram saved in some format?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found for this was to use the "Print" menu, but instead of saving as a PDF I increased the zoom so that the diagram took up the totality of my screen and then took a screenshot using Mac's screenshot tool. This gave me a `.png` with higher resolution than I could ever want.

Comment: Amazing tip.  Zoom in and your saved image is higher resolution.  Unexpected but true.